# Yarn Link All Packages/Workspaces

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Yarn's [link](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/) allows you to register a local package for symlinking into another local package. To use `link` you cd into the package directory and run `yarn link`. This works fine on individual packages, however I have a monorepo, using Yarn's workspaces alongside Lerna. There are many packages, and I would like a simple way of linking all the packages within the monorepo.

My `package.json`:

```
…
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
…
```

My `lerna.json`:

```
{
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true,
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  …
}
```

**Is there a simple way to run `yarn link` (and `yarn unlink`) on each package?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lerna provides the [exec](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/exec) command to 'Run an arbitrary command in each package':

link.sh

```sh
lerna exec -- yarn link
```

unlink.sh

```sh
lerna exec -- yarn unlink
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

If I may offer a pure Yarn solution.

Using the [Yarn workspace-tools plugin](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/HEAD/packages/plugin-workspace-tools/README.md) you can make use of the [Yarn foreach command](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/foreach) to run a command on all workspaces.

To add the plugin run:

```
yarn plugin import workspace-tools
```

**Usage:**

```
yarn workspaces foreach <commandName> ...
```

**Example:**

unlink:

```
yarn workspaces foreach run unlink
```

link:

```
yarn workspaces foreach run link
```

I would suggest adding 1 command in each workspace with the same name which unlinks and links the required local dependencies then calling them all with one foreach command.

***Edited****

After re-reading your inital question I realise you're using Yarn Workspaces which means you don't even need to use Yarn Link at all to have one local package be a dependency in another package.

From the directory of the package which requires the local package run:

```
yarn add <PACKAGE NAME>@*
```

Where `<PACKAGE NAME>` is the name of the required package.

To confirm the dependency was successfully added run:

```
yarn workspaces info
```

And confirm your dependency was added it should look like this:

```
{
  // Rest of the workspace info
  "<DEPENDANT PACKAGE>": {
    "location": "packages/<DEPENDANT PACKAGE>",
    "workspaceDependencies": [
      "<DEPENDENCY PACKAGE>"
    ],
    "mismatchedWorkspaceDependencies": []
  },
}
```

If your IDE complains about `"Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations"` be sure to re-build the package.