# How to link a package from a monorepo that is using `yarn workspaces`?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, redux-toolkit, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo using `yarn workspaces`. It is actually the repo of [redux-toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit). I made some modifications on the toolkit package and I would like to test it locally with `yarn link` in another package.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998591/yarn-link-all-packages-workspaces)
so I tried `yarn workspaces foreach -A run link` resulting in

```
Done in 0s
```

but when I try get the list of links with `ls ~/.config/yarn/link`, it's empty. When I try to link it in the other package using `yarn link @reduxjs/toolkit`, nothing happens.

Running `yarn link` in the *./packages/toolkit* directory gives me the same result.

my yarn version: 4.0.2
node version: 18.18.0